# Firestore error: A document must have an even number of path elements

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to update a document in Firestore and add a few fields that track the status of processing of that file.

The problem is that I'm getting the error: "A document must have an even number of path elements"

However, the path of the document is:

`orders/orders_files_logs/orders_processing_status/A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2_Orders-2022_08_18-01-03-24`

I've have a method in Python that I wrote and call when updating a document and it works, for documents in a different collection. The path to the other collection is shorter, though: `/orders/orders_metadata`.

I'm not exactly sure what I can do to fix this. The definiton of the Python method is simply:

```
def update_firestore_document(self, document_id, updated_information):
    self._collection.document(document_id).update(updated_information)
```

And I call this method with:

```
update_firestore_document(
    document_id = 'orders/orders_files_logs/orders_processing_status/A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2_Orders-2022_08_18-01-03-24',  
    updated_information = {'processed':'Success'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to found out the problem myself. When initializing the connection to the Firestore database using:

```
firestore_status_processor = FirestoreConnector(collection='orders', app_name='orders_processor')
```

where the definition of the `FirestoreConnector` class is:

```
def __init__(self, collection, app_name='[DEFAULT]'):
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(self._credentials, {'projectId': self._project_id}, name=app_name)
    self.__initialize_firestore_client_connection()
    self.__set_firestore_collection(collection=collection)

def __initialize_firestore_client_connection(self):
    self._database = firestore.client()

def __set_firestore_collection(self, collection):
    self._collection = self._database.collection(collection)
```

It seems that in my original code, where I call the `firestore_status_processor.update_firestore_document()` with the parameters I mentioned in my question, which the most important one is:

```
document_id = 'orders/orders_files_logs/orders_processing_status/A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2_Orders-2022_08_18-01-03-24'
```

By manually adding in the `orders/` at the beginning, I am essentially breaking the path that is defined by the default Firebase client.

When debugging I notice that the actual path it was trying to write to was:

```
projects/(project-id)/database/(default)/documents/orders//orders/order_files_logs/orders_processing_status/A2EUQ1WTGCTBG2_Orders-2022_08_18-01-03-24
```

Removing the extra `orders/` from the document_id parameter, when calling the update_firestore_document method did the trick.